# Is the set of smooth functions with zero mean dense in the space of Sobolev functions with zero mean?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Given a Lipschitz domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I know that the space of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support $C^\infty_0 (\Omega) $ is dense in the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) = \{v\in W^{1,p}(\Omega): v|_{\partial\Omega} = 0\}$.

What I am wondering is, if I let $ V =\{v\in W^{1,p}(\Omega) : \int_\Omega v dx = 0\}$ and let $T = \{v\in C^\infty(\overline \Omega): \int_\Omega v dx = 0\}$, 
then is $T$ dense in $V$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. Let's prove it in this way.

Take $V$ as you defined, first notice that it is any closed subset of $W^{1,p}$ with respect to $W^{1,p}$ norm.

Now, since $\Omega$ process a good boundary, we could find $(u_n)\subset C^\infty(\bar \Omega)$ such that $u_n\to u\in V$ in $W^{1,p}$ norm.

Now we define 
$$ v_n\equiv u_n-\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega u_n$$
and hence $v_n\in T$.

We have $\nabla v_n=\nabla u_n$ and hence $\nabla v_n\to \nabla u$ in $L^p$. Moreover,
$$ \|v_n-u\|_{L^p}\leq \|u_n-u\|_{L^p}+\|\int_\Omega u_n\|_{L^p}\to 0 $$
where 
$$ \|\int_\Omega u_n\|_{L^p}\to 0 $$
bt LDCT.

Therefore, $T$ is dense in $V$.

---

As be pointed out in comment, we could use Poincare to prove that 
$$\|v_n-u\|_{L^p}^p\leq C\|\nabla u_n-\nabla u\|_{L^p}^p\to 0$$

Comment: to show T is dense in V, don't I need to show the convergence in $W^{1,p}$ norm not in just $L_2$ norm?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, it is just a typo

Comment: Alternatively, Poincare's inequality gives that $\| \nabla u\|_p$ gives an equivalent norm in $V$ and then the result is obvious as you noted.

Comment: @Jose27 This is great! I will add it in my answer.

Comment: Minor note: you need to scale the integral in your definition of $v_n$, i.e. $v_n=u_n-\frac1{\lambda(\Omega)}\int u_n$

Comment: Are sure, of course! @Jason

Comment: @wisher when you show ∥∫ Ω u n ∥ L p  →0 by LDCT, could you tell me more in detail how you apply the LDCT? I am not too familiar with the theorem. What is you dominating function?

Comment: Maybe LDCT is a bit overkill here. I think Holder is enough here. Also, for a shortcut, please look at Jose27's comment or the update in my post

Comment: And could $V$ be dense in $W^{1,p}$??